# How to display picture from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

Hi i'm using this code to save a picture into mysql data base 
saved.php

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'foryou');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());


function NewUser()
{
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO apartments (image) VALUES ('$image')";
    $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data) {
    echo "Info saved";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    SignUp();
}
?>`
```

and this is the code fro display all what i got is the name of image any help

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'foryou');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$query = "select * from apartments";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>

<body class="metrouicss" onload="prettyPrint()" style="zoom: 1;">
<div id="container">

<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <div class="item tile double bg-color-red">
        <?php echo date("Y/m/d")?><br>
        <?php echo $row['info']?><br>
        <?php echo $row['image']?><br>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

<body>
<img src="getImage.php?id=1" width="175" height="200" />
</body>
<?php

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // do some validation here to ensure id is safe

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("apartments");
  $sql = "SELECT image FROM apartments WHERE id=1";
  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  mysql_close($link);
  echo $row['image'];
?>
```

i am using this code for picture upload

```
<form method="POST" action="saved.php">
<input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Password"  class="style">
</form>
```

how can i display the image saved in mysql

Comment: `$_FILES` -Please look into the link for files handling  http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Does your insert code really work? Whatever, this has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP. You need to learn how to insert pictures in HTML.

Comment: You also have gratuitous misuse of the body tag in there. You should look into general structure of html first. Then worry about php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a folder named 'uploads' which all uploaded pictures stores in it and they re name in database.

Now:

```
...
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'foryou');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con =mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("apartments");
$sql = "SELECT image FROM apartments WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
...
<img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?>" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can display the image like that

```
  <img src="Path_to_image/<?php echo $row['image'] ;?>.jpeg" width="175" height="200" />
```

if `$row['image']` is the name of the image.

Comment: assuming of course that he changed his form to accept `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as well as using `$_FILES['image']` and then actually storing the image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload images through HTML form, you have to use **enctype="multipart/form-data"**.. i have edited your code. try this.

```
<form method="POST" action="saved.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Password"  class="style">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this:

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
readfile($_POST["filename"]);
```

on another php file (let's say yourfile.php)
then you can do:

```
<img src="yourfile.php?filename=blablabla" />
```

basically your php file will be a dynamic image which shows up as an image or another depending on the $filename variable

obviously you have to set/detect the right mime type (png, jpeg, gif and such...)